# auto reply not working only for gmail accounts using php mail()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a contact form on my website which sends an email to my account and an auto-response to the users who fills the form. I could able to send an auto-reply to non-Gmail accounts but not to Gmail accounts, it's not even sent to spam. I want to know is anything missing in the code, or any settings have to be changed, let me know

code is working fine with non-Gmail accounts

```
<?php
$email_to = 'mailme@example.com'; //your email
$business = 'company name.,'; //business name
//$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$autoResponse = true; //set to false if you don't want to send an auto reply
$autoResponseSubject = "Demo Contact Form";
$autoResponseMessage = "Hi, thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon.";
$autoResponseHeaders = "From: $business <$email_to>\r\n";
$autoResponseHeaders .= "Reply-To: $business <$email_to>\r\n";

$headers = "From: $name <$email_from>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $name <$email_from>\r\n";

if(@mail($email_to,$subject, $message, $headers)){
 if($autoResponse === true){
  mail($email_from, $autoResponseSubject, $autoResponseMessage, $autoResponseHeaders);
 }
 echo '1';
} else {
 echo '0';
}
?>
```

I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Google, Microsoft, and the like, only accept email from mail servers that fulfill a number of requirements. These requirements are changing over time. This has mainly to do with preventing spam.

Things start with SPF, which is rather simple, but the normal site providing documentation has been down since feb 2019. Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) instead.

The next thing is [DKIM](http://dkim.org/). Without it mail certainly won't been accepted by GMail.

Then there is also [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/overview).

After all of this there is still no guarantee that your mail will be accepted. Your IP could be blacklisted.

As you can probably guess by now, running your own mail server is a lot of work. I've stopped doing it years ago. I now use a third party service for this.

Comment: all my other emails also  going to spam folder only, is there any way to overcome it so that this code works to send an auto reply gmail accounts too

Comment: Read the answer I gave and check the link in the answer.

Comment: i am not using g-suite

Comment: That is true... You still need to do these things though. I'll change the links.

Comment: @vedhasoft2 Changed the answer so there's no link to the g-suite anymore.

Comment: no other options, is there anything missing in my code

Comment: except php mailer is there any option to use the same code to send auto reply to gmail accounts

Comment: @vedhasoft2 You have to authenticate your mailserver, before GMail will accept mail from it.

Comment: i had called to godaddy they are telling its wrong in the script, telling to review my script. so may i know what is wrong in the code.

Comment: @vedhasoft2 How did GoDaddy explain that your code is working fine with non-Gmail accounts?

Comment: no they are telling script itself is wrong but i asked them how could i able to recieve to other accounts why the problem is only with gmail for that they din't say anything and they said to review my code

Comment: again i checked its working fine with yahoo too but not with gmail